# LibreOffice linking to bibliography

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

Hello I am writing my bachelor thesis in LibreOffice-Writer (Version: 6.3.6.2) and have a problem with the bibliography.

I have created the corresponding bibliography and can refer to it in the text. But unfortunately the entries in the text are not linked to the entry in the bibliography. So I cannot click in the text on the entry e.g.: [1] to jump to the entry in the bibliography.

Do I really have to link the entries in the text by hand, or does anyone have an idea how to do this automatically.

I am grateful for every suggestion.

Comment: I recommend taking a look at "Chapter 15 Tables of Contents, Indexes, Bibliographies" in the [LibreOffice Writer Guide](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Documentation/Publications#LibreOffice_Writer_Guide). From a cursory glance, it seems that setting up a bibliography can be a bit complicated.

Comment: @DavidYockey Thank you for reading my question. I took a look at the document you linked and was able to learn something about the styling of the bibliography (thanks for that), but unfortunately there was nothing about my question. I feel so incredibly stupid, since I don't actually want to do anything exotic. :-)

Gradually I'm asking myself if this is even possible in LibreOffice.